# Oracle: how to formulate a complex constraint with case when

Tags: oracle, check-constraints

The following conditional constraint simply doesn't work. Is it possible to formulate in a working way?

```
ALTER TABLE eni_trasc_voci_pwr_fatt
ADD CONSTRAINT tvp_constraint_1 CHECK (
CASE WHEN TVP_CODICE_ASSOGGETAMEN = '-' THEN tvp_regione IS NULL
END);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE eni_trasc_voci_pwr_fatt
ADD CONSTRAINT tvp_constraint_1 CHECK (
CASE WHEN TVP_CODICE_ASSOGGETAMEN = '-' THEN tvp_regione else null end IS NULL);
```

Comment: You're right. But my intention was to describe one full "Case when"-Statement, because that one in the question was totally false.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want logical implication here ("if X then Y"), which is logically equivalent to "(not X) or Y".  CASE is used to create a finite map.

Your constraint should be something like

`TVP_CODICE_ASSOGGETAMEN != '-' OR TVP_REGIONE IS NULL`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do what you want without the case statement:

```
create table t1 (c1 varchar2(10), c2 varchar2(10));

alter table t1 add constraint t1_chk1 check ( (c1 = '-' and c2 is null) or (c1 != '-' and c2 is not null) );
```

Now try and insert some values:

```
SQL> insert into t1 values ('-', 'reject');
insert into t1 values ('-', 'reject')  
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SODONNEL.T1_CHK1) violated


SQL>
SQL> insert into t1 values ('-', null);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t1 values ('a', null);
insert into t1 values ('a', null)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SODONNEL.T1_CHK1) violated


SQL>
SQL> insert into t1 values ('a', 'accept');

1 row created.
```